# Mix numbers in Javascript number array to a single number

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this : `const array = [1, 3, 5, 6];`
I want to know how can i mix this numbers together?
so i can have something like this in output : `1356`

Comment: Do you want an actual number, or a string?

Comment: I want an actual number

Comment: Then you can do the logic in the duplicate, or the line below, and then stick it inside `parseInt()`, `Number()`, or put a `+` in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) in order to concatenate all the array elements together.

```js
const array = [1, 3, 5, 6]
console.log(array.join(""));
```